# How to have Fiddler\ other application automatically intercept and modify HTTP requests parameters?

Tags: javascript, http, google-chrome-extension, url-rewriting, requestly

I work with a website that I dont own\ coded. Now, I need to change one of the params on the requests that are sent from this website to the server.

Example:
From:

```
https://google.com/search?count=20
```

To:

```
https://google.com/search?count=40
```

I tried and succeeded changing the param with Fiddler but I want it to be done automatically for every request that is sent from my pc.

I also tried [Requestly](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/requestly-redirect-url-mo/mdnleldcmiljblolnjhpnblkcekpdkpa), which is a chrome extension that is capable of modifying params, but it also messes with the response headers.
Instead of sending:

```
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: he-IL,he;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: application/json
sec-ch-ua: "Google Chrome";v="95", "Chromium";v="95", ";Not A Brand";v="99"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-site
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/95.0.4638.69 Safari/537.36
```

as headers, it only sends:

```
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/95.0.4638.69 Safari/537.36
```

Any suggestions here?

Answer (score 1):

[Requestly](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/requestly-redirect-url-mo/mdnleldcmiljblolnjhpnblkcekpdkpa) doesn't modify the response headers if you have configured [a QueryParams Rule](https://medium.com/requestly-docs/introducing-query-param-rule-d152b28eec08)

You can create a Modify QueryParams rule like this

[image]

As per [the documentation](https://medium.com/requestly-docs/introducing-query-param-rule-d152b28eec08)

- The rule will add the parameter `q` with value `40` if the parameter doesn't exist
- The rule will change the value of parameter `q` to `40` if the parameter already exists in the URL.

For Requestly related questions, I'd suggest using the QnA section - https://github.com/requestly/requestly/discussions/categories/q-a